# jQuery ignores delay when using remove

Tags: jquery

I need to `fadeOut()` a row and then `remove()` it so it does not show when I filter table later. The problem is when I add the `remove()` function, the delay is ignored:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.change').on('click', function(){
            $(this).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            var row = $(this).closest('.auction-data');
            var price = +row.find('.price').data('price');
            var inputPrice = row.find('.input-price').val(price);
            row.fadeOut(2000).delay(1000).remove();
        });
    });
```

When I chage `remove()` into `fadeIn()` (for testing purposes), the `delay()` function works.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Delay()` only delay animatios, not functions.
You can `remove` element when `fadeOut` finish.

```
row.fadeOut(2000, function(){$(this).remove()})
```

or use `setTimeout()`

```
row.fadeOut(2000);
setTimeout(function(){row.remove()},3000); //2000 from animation and 1000 for wait.
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that about the delay() function although it seems pretty basic. Thank you, I used the first version and it works like a charm. I mark your answer in a couple of minutes (as soon as stack allows me)